# .NET - Telerik RadComboBox Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I use a telerik combobox control in my web app form. In my skin I place the following line:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" Skin="Windows7" />
```

The control is then added to the page and the skin is applied. This works fine in firefox but in internet explorer the background disappeara when the list drops down (see **Absence Reason**):

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Check how many CSS you are loading. IE have max of 32 individual CSS'es loaded. Telerik theme has ~ 20 static and many generated on the fly. 
IE usually won't notify you about that and simply stop processing additional CSS

There are 2 solutions -

**The first** is to simply drop all the static CSS into single  one 
(you have single CSS file single for each element - such as grid,input,calender and etc)

```
type *.css > C:\telerik.css
```

**The second**, and more "pretty" solution is to use [RadDtyleSheetManager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html) .

Personally I've never tried the second solution, I simply  "cat"ed all the CSS  files into single "telerik.css" file.